# Undefined variable: title (View: resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi my laravel app is giving me this error when i click on login: Undefined variable: title (View: \resources\views\auth\login.blade.php) and m following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/laravel-multiple-guards-authentication-setup-and-login-2761564da986
how can i resolve it anyone can suggest me??

blade file:

```
   @extends('layouts.app')
  @section('content')
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">{{ $title }}</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route($loginRoute) }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                    {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{ __('Login') }}
                            </button>
                            @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route($forgotPasswordRoute) }}">
                                    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                </a>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  @endsection
```

controller:

```
   public function showLoginForm()
   {
    return view('auth.login',[
        'title' => 'Login',
        'loginRoute' => 'login',
        'forgotPasswordRoute' => 'password.request',
    ]);
   }
```

route:

```
  Route::get('/login','LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

Comment: clear view cache : `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: still same error

Comment: Did you changed route recently? try: php artisan optimize

Comment: Have you tried `with` like `return view('auth.login')->with([
        'title' => 'Login',
        'loginRoute' => 'login',
        'forgotPasswordRoute' => 'password.request'
    ]);`

Comment: show your `layouts.app`blade file

Comment: @DhananjayKyada still same error

Comment: @SaurabhMistry  this is layouts.app paste.ofcode.org/G68gdsNY327rB7LChtuUwn

Comment: Is your LoginController in Auth folder ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand what are you passing is it a session or variable

Please give the following code try,

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $title = 'Login Page';
    $pageData = [
        'title'               => 'Login',
        'loginRoute'          => 'login',
        'forgotPasswordRoute' => route('password.request'),
    ];
    return view('auth.login',compact('pageData','title');
}
```

Usage in blade

```
{{ $pageData['title'] }} // Login

{{ $title }} // Login
```

After that run the following command

```
composer dump // composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: sorry its still same

Answer (score 1):

try with a different name :

```
public function showLoginForm()
   {
    return view('auth.login')->with([
        'page_title' => 'Login',
        'loginRoute' => 'login',
        'forgotPasswordRoute' => 'password.request',
    ]);
   }
```

in your view :

```
{{ $page_title ? $page_title :'No Title Found' }}
```